# how to partiton the text file?

Tags: algorithm, split

i have a file having strings of 5 characters each.they are to be seperated in the basis of their 1st character.

input file-
AA01J
AA01K
AA01L
BA01J
BA01K
.
.
.
.
ZA01K
ZA01L

I want 26 files each having these strings on the basis of their first character.

Comment: Sounds trivial.. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is not data mining. Not even close.

To **split a file by the first character** is a trivial programming task for computer science 101.